# Module is not available, misspelled or forgot to load (but I didn't)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, module, angularjs-injector

I am fairly new to angular and using it with JSON api files. TO test, I am trying to use the free github api (my names for functions are for a different json api that i will be working with later). I just wanted to see if my functions were working with `console.log()`, but i receive this error in the console.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   MesaViewer due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MesaViewer' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

I have spelled `MesaViewer` the exact same in both, and dependencies are seen in the second line!

```
var app = angular.module("MesaViewer");
var MainController = function($scope, $location, $http, $routeParams) {
```

What did I do wrong?
Here is my plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/sZPaFbzbOB6AmVCLL1vq

Comment: as a part of the syntax, `[]` is mandatory. It is used to add dependencies in to your app, e.g., other modules. like `['yourModuleName', 'anotherModule']`. You still got to include the blank array, `[]` even if you have no dependencies on other modules.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It should be

```
var app = angular.module("MesaViewer", []);
```

This is the syntax you need to define a module and you need the array to show it has no dependencies.

You use the

```
angular.module("MesaViewer");
```

syntax when you are referencing a module you've already defined.

Comment: And make sure that if you have multiple js files referenced in your HTML, that the one where the module is defined is loaded first, or you will still get a "nomod" error, even if you have declared it.

Answer (score 15):

You are improperly declaring your main module, it requires a second dependencies array argument when creating a module, otherwise it is a reference to an existing module

Change:

```
var app = angular.module("MesaViewer");
```

To:

```
var app = angular.module("MesaViewer",[]);
```

<kbd>**[Working Version](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fq6iqlwZHuueWPJj9lNU?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error and fixed it.
It turned out to be a silly reason.

> This was the culprit: `<script src="app.js"/>`
>
> Fix: `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Make sure your script tag is ended properly!

Comment: Possibly even sillier for me! I had accidentally typed the src as "/js/app.js", when what I really wanted was "js/app.js" without the initial slash. That meant it worked in one development environment but not another!

Answer (score 7):

I found this question when I got the same error for a different reason.

My issue was that my Gulp hadn't picked up on the fact that I had declared a new module and I needed to manually re-run Gulp.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when my service declaration was inside a non-invoked function (IIFE). The last line below did NOT have the extra () to run and define the service.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("reviewService", [])
        .service("reviewService", reviewService);

    function reviewService($http, $q, $log) {
        //
    }
}());
```

Comment: someone give this guy a medal. Thanks Todd.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to AngularJS but was sure I had declared the module correctly, it was driving me nuts. This was the cure!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, but I resolved adding  jquery.min.js  before angular.min.js.

Answer (score 4):

make sure that you insert your module and controller in your index.html first.
then use this code in your module  `var app = angular.module("MesaViewer", []);`

Answer (score 2):

Using `AngularJS` 1.6.9+

There is one more incident, it also happen when you declare variable name different of module name.

```
var indexPageApp = angular.module('indexApp', []);
```

to get rid of this error,

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'indexPageApp' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

change the module name similar to var declared name or vice versa -

```
var indexPageApp = angular.module('indexPageApp', []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but i resolved it, it was a syntax error in the AngularJS provider