# Unable to repro unavailable Angular Module error

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

Following is how my controller in Angular 1.x looks like -

```
const app = angular.module("userRegistration", [
  "some-dep",
  "templates",
  "ngRoute",
  "ngResource",
  "ngCookies",
  "userRegistration.controllers",
  "userRegistration.services",
  "userRegistration.directives"
]);
```

Everything runs fine but once in a while, the following error surfaces, mostly on a windows machine with Chrome browser version >= 62 -

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module userRegistration due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'userRegistration' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I came to know from another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394919/1323517) that the issue lies in the syntax. The correct syntax is

```
var app = angular.module("MesaViewer", []);
```

But I am not sure why this error never sprang up in past. I tried to repro the issue on the same chrome browser version but was unable to.

Comment: post all your module code

Comment: I cant because 1. that's business logic and 2. not sure how it would help. It doesn't have any logic related to loading the module which is where the current error is happening.

Comment: we dont need the whole code, the error is thrown from not the module you have posted its from userRegistration

Comment: Far too little known to solve a *"once in a while"* bug

Comment: you have async modules loading? Then it can be some sort of race condition.

Comment: @Sajeetharan shared the code where the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov that explains the once in a while nature of it. Would look in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try this..

```
const app = angular.module("userRegistration", [
  "some-dep",
  "templates",
  "ngRoute",
  "ngResource",
  "ngCookies"
]);
```

There is not need to inject the controller, services, etc from the same module

Comment: I will try this but I would never know if this fixes the issue until it re-occurs OR stops occurring in production as I am unable to repro this issue locally